# ¿Como creo un proxy para luego añadirlo a mi webservice?

Tags: c#, .net, webservice, proxy

Actualmente tengo código que envia data a un ws en un servidor remoto, pero cuando lo subo a mi servidor me sale el error `407 proxy authentication required` y me gustaría saber como añado un proxy a mi ws para que este no tenga ese error:

Codigo actual (C#).

```
        NodoReturn = "<request><entry>" + nodo.InnerXml + "</entry></request>";
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx", "xxx");


        request.Timeout = 60000;
        request.ContinueTimeout = 60000;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
        request.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

        byte[] bByteArray = e.GetBytes(NodoReturn);


        using (Stream sRequestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            sRequestStream.Write(bByteArray, 0, bByteArray.Length);
            sRequestStream.Flush();
            sRequestStream.Close();

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream sDataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sDataStream);
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                        sDataStream.Close();
                        response.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Según yo, todo esta de forma correcta, no agregue el ws mediante un web reference en visual studio, debido a que cuando lo intentaba agregar me descargaba un json y no me permitía realizar ninguna otra acción.
El servidor en donde se alojara el ws no tendrá ningún navegador disponible por lo que no puedo obtener el proxy por default de ninguno de los navegadores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta definir la dirección del proxy y sus credenciales para poder acceder al internet:

```
var NodoReturn = "<request><entry>" + nodo.InnerXml + "</entry></request>";
            HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") as HttpWebRequest;
```

//adiciona estas dos líneas:

```
            request.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("https:// direccion proxy");
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "contraseña", "dominio");

            request.Method = "POST";


            request.Timeout = 60000;
            request.ContinueTimeout = 60000;
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Date = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
            request.IfModifiedSince = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.Accept = "application/xml";
            Encoding e = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");

            byte[] bByteArray = e.GetBytes(NodoReturn);


            using (Stream sRequestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                sRequestStream.Write(bByteArray, 0, bByteArray.Length);
                sRequestStream.Flush();
                sRequestStream.Close();

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream sDataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(sDataStream);
                        {
                            reader.Close();
                            sDataStream.Close();
                            response.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Espero que te sirva.